# SQL Server Full text Index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using full text index for search the list of members in a stored procedure. But it through following error,

> Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s).

I got the advice from Google to use below query,

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

But it has no result, the same error occur.

Comment: What is the error that occurs? Can you supply the code of your sproc?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the noise words list for sql server either to add new words or to remove words.

See [HERE](http://arcanecode.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/creating-and-customizing-noise-words-in-sql-server-2005-full-text-search/) how to.

If you remove all the noise words, then your index size will certainly grow. This could make your searches take a bit longer - but how much longer depends on your data.

---

If you change the noise words list, it affect all dbs. You'd need to repopulate your full-text catalog so that the words you've removed from the noise word list would get picked up in the indexes.

Comment: If you choose to edit the stoplist (and you happen to be using the "system" stoplist), you should really consider making a copy, editing the copy, and using the copy as the stoplist for your FTI.

Another option is to remove the stoplist all together...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx