# Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s)

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Full text Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755866/sql-server-full-text-index)
>   [SQL Server stored procedure parameter output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756609/sql-server-stored-procedure-parameter-output)

I am using full text index for search the list of members in a stored procedure. But it through following error,

```
Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s).
```

I got the advice from Google to use below query,

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

But it has no result, the same error occur.

I got one more solution for use stop words, but i don't have idea about this.

One more thing is I am using remote sql server so i cannot able to create and edit a new text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some quotes with the variable names like:

firstname = "Rajesh"
lastname = "Ramesh"